# Необходимо узнать, содержится ли одно изображение в другом

Tags: python, изображения, opencv

У меня есть одна проблема, с которой я не могу разобраться примерно 5 часов.
В общем, мне просто необходимо узнать последовательность чисел с изображения, но что бы я не пробовал, все упирается в то, что эти числа прописные. Поэтому я решил использовать "шаблонное" изображение, и пытаться найти среди всех шаблонов наибольшее сходство. Поэтому, я уже пробовал:

- imagehash
- opencv template matching
- opencv hist matching

Конечно, возможно где-то я ошибся с аргументами или чем-то еще, но наиболее близкие результаты к правильным были у метода template matching. По идее звучит даже логично, у меня есть большее изображение, 100% содержащее какое-то из меньших, его нужно найти. Но даже так происходят неточности, например 1 и 10, 5 и 3, и т.п.
Как я получаю изображение? Ну, сначала я захватываю необходимую область с помощью pyscreenshot. После чего, с помощью PIL заменяю все лишние цвета на белый и сохраняю картинку с названием "temp+случаное число". Для примера я прикреплю несколько изображений.
Если вы можете помочь мне решить данную проблему я буду очень благодарен.

[image: Шаблон 9]

[image: Полученное изображение, необходимо понять что это 9]

Comment: Без нейросетей тут вряд ли что-то толковое получится. Нужно сегментировать цифры, а потом опознать с помощью CNN сети. Вообще, для чего вы это делаете? Если чтобы распознавать капчу, то проще купить на специальных сайтах услугу и распознавать индусами 1000 капч за 1$ (цену уже точно не помню), чем возиться с этим всем.

Comment: Погуглите в частности примеры про MNIST digits dataset. Можно попробовать и без нейросетей в принципе, но сильно зависит от того, как у вас цифры трансформируются или они довольно одинаковые каждый раз.